# FailedGetPodsMetric: for HPA autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, autoscaling, hpa

I am trying to autoscale using custom metrics, with metric type "http_request". My following command is showing correct output:

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/" | jq
```

Below is my hpa.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: podinfo
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: podinfo
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metricName: http_requests
      targetAverageValue: 1
```

but my scaling is failing due to

```
the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: 
unable to get metric http_requests: unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: an error on the server` 
("Internal Server Error: \"/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods/%!A(MISSING)/http_requests?labelSelector=app%!D(MISSING)podinfo\": the server could not find the requested resource") 
has prevented the request from succeeding (get pods.custom.metrics.k8s.io *)
```

Please help me out in this :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing pods in your cluster that match the provided deployment specification. Can you check if your `podinfo` deployment is running? And that it has healthy pods in it?

The command works because you're only checking the availability of the `metrics` endpoint. This simply implies that the endpoint is live to start providing metrics, doesn't guarantee that you will receive metrics (without any resources).

Comment: Both my deployment and service for podinfo are healthy and successfully created. But, still hpa metrics context not working.

Comment: What is the namespace your pods are running into?